# Can't install Scipy properly

Tags: anaconda

All!

I've bumped into a problem when installing scipy.

```
Command 
"C:\Users\jcajandi\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\envs\py35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jcajandi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-805uir10\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jcajandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-54j3kyss-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jcajandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-805uir10\scipy\
```

I can't understand this. What should I do to complete the installation?

Comment: `conda install scipy` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `conda install scipy` does the trick but will cause problems in importing numpy. Need to put 'r' before the file paths in the _config.py file.